# Existe algum meio de dar as colunas uma largura automatica?

Tags: c#, vb.net, itextsharp, relatório

Estou montando um relatório via ItextSharp e ja li a respeito de como atribuir larguras específicas as colunas do PdfPTable, entretanto gostaria que essa largura fosse atribuida automaticamente de acordo com o conteúdo que as colunas possuem.

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1):

Considerando que o relatório é construido a partir de um array contendo o conteudo da tabela, e um vetor contendo seu cabecalho, então basta utilizar este metodo para obter o vetor com os devidos tamanhos das colunas.

```
Public Function getColsize(ByVal Dados(,) As String, ByVal Header As String(), ByVal FtCalculo As Font)
    Dim L As Integer
    Dim C As Integer
    Dim nLin As Integer
    Dim nCol As Integer
    Dim Colsize() As Integer
    Dim chk As Chunk

    nCol = Dados.GetUpperBound(1)
    nLin = Dados.GetUpperBound(0)

    ReDim Colsize(nCol)

    Dim B As BaseFont = FtCalculo.GetCalculatedBaseFont(False)

    For C = 0 To nCol
        'chk = New Chunk(Header(C).ToUpper, Ft2)
        'Colsize(C) = Math.Ceiling(chk.GetWidthPoint)
        Colsize(C) = Math.Ceiling(B.GetWidthPoint(Header(C).ToUpper, FtCalculo.Size)) + 2
    Next C

    For C = 0 To nCol
        For L = 0 To nLin
            chk = New Chunk(Dados(L, C), FtCalculo)
            If Colsize(C) < (Math.Ceiling(chk.GetWidthPoint) + 2) Then
                Colsize(C) = (Math.Ceiling(chk.GetWidthPoint) + 2)
            End If
        Next L
    Next C

    Return Colsize

End Function
```